# PDO Array Error

Tags: php, pdo

```
$duyuru1 = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM duyurular WHERE id = ?");
$duyuru1->execute(array('1'));
$duyuru1->fetchAll();

$duyuru2 = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM duyurular WHERE id = ?");
$duyuru2->execute(array('2'));
$duyuru2->fetchAll();

$duyuru3 = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM duyurular WHERE id = ?");
$duyuru3->execute(array('3'));
$duyuru3->fetchAll();

$duyuru4 = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM duyurular WHERE id = ?");
$duyuru4->execute(array('4'));
$duyuru4->fetchAll();

$duyuru5 = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM duyurular WHERE id = ?");
$duyuru5->execute(array('5'));
$duyuru5->fetchAll();
```

Line 72: `<?php echo $duyuru1['baslik'] ?>`

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in index.php on line 72

Comment: You don't need to prepare since you've nothing "to" prepare. Just query `$PDO->query`. **Do** read up on the subject http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Why are you doing `->execute(array('1'))` without any `?`s in your query?  Also, you need to `fetch()` your results in order to use them.

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// set exception handling to report SQL errors
$PDO->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    // prepare statement once
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM duyurular WHERE id = ?");

    // execute statement & fetch data for first row as associative array.
    $stmt->execute(array('1'));
    $duyuru1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Execute same statement again with new argument. Fetch data
    $stmt->execute(array('2'));
    $duyuru2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // repeat for remaining arguments.
    $stmt->execute(array('3'));
    $duyuru3 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt->execute(array('4'));
    $duyuru4 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt->execute(array('5'));
    $duyuru5 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Exception lands here. Report problem and exit.
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

...later...

```
<?php echo $duyuru1['baslik'] ?>
```

This assumes that the `id` is unique in your table - if not you need more code to retrieve the remaining rows.

This is also a clumsy way of retrieving multiple rows from a database. You'd be better improving your query and retrieving all the rows into an array at once, but that's a separate question.